# Best way to organize structures in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I would like each Card to show the name of the list and additional text below. Next to it is the total amount.

[This is how it turned out:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwLcR.png)

```
@Composable
fun ListOfItems(list: Lists) {
Card(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(100.dp)
        .padding(5.dp),
    elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
        defaultElevation = 10.dp
    ),


    ) {
    Column {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            Text(
                text = list.listName,
                fontSize = (20.sp)
            )
            Text(
                text = list.totalValue.toString(),
            )

        }

        Text(
            text = list.listName,
            fontSize = (20.sp)
        )

    }


}}
```

[This is how i imagine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRxSs.png)

What is the best way to do it?

Separate into columns? Grid? Other way ?

Answer (score 0):

add another column and put the text in one and the total in the other

```
@Composable
fun ListOfItems(list: Lists) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(5.dp),
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
            defaultElevation = 10.dp
        ),
    ) {
        Column {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(8.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
            ) {
                // Left side
                Column {
                    Text(
                        text = list.listName,
                        fontSize = 20.sp
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = "some Text", 
                        fontSize = 14.sp,
                        color = Color.Gray 
                    )
                }

                // Right side
                Text(
                    text = list.totalValue.toString(),
                    fontSize = 20.sp
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I kind of understand you overall. It already helped, but if I want to change the value, how do I center it?

`
 // Right side
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
                    text = list.totalValue.toString(),
                    fontSize = 30.sp,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
`

I just increased the size but I know it should be a better way

Answer (score 0):

```
@Composable
 fun ListOfItems(list: Lists) {
Card(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(5.dp),
    elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
        defaultElevation = 10.dp
    ),
) {
    Column {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(100.dp)
                .padding(10.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically

        ) {
            // Left side
            Column {
                Text(
                    text = list.listName,
                    fontSize = 20.sp
                )
                Text(
                    text = "some Text",
                    fontSize = 14.sp,
                    color = Color.Gray
                )
            }

            // Right side
            Row (
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ){
                Text(

                    text = list.totalValue.toString(),
                    fontSize = 30.sp,
                )
            }

        }
    }
}}
```

This was the final solution